# How to send event click to factory Angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I tried to send `event` to factory like as:

**HTML**

```
ng-click="deleteUser(event, <?=$val->subscribetouserId?>);"
```

**Angular JS**

```
$scope.deleteUser = function(event, idUser){
    userFactory.delete(idUser, event);
}
```

So, I can see `userFactory` which I send `event` from click

In method `delete` I have wrote:

```
angular.element(event.target).closest('.item').remove();
```

It gives me error:

> Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Comment: i think you need to use `$event` instead of `event`

Comment: Don't remove the element, remove the data and angular will remove element for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use ngClick directive, it creates an object named $event on the current scope.

You can send it to the controller like this:

```
ng-click="deleteUser($event, ...)"
```

The other thing I would like to turn your attention to is that you should avoid altering the DOM from the controller/factory. If you have an array of users, then you should use ngRepeat to render it. When you delete the user in the deleteUser function, you should also remove it from the array you use to populate the ngRepeat directive. That way, angular will remove the item from the DOM, and you won't have to remove it by yourself.